# Communicating between appengine and an application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, post, get

I'm working on a web interface which currently runs using PHP and communicates locally to a python script.

I'm moving the web side to appengine, which so far is going well when being used locally, I'm currently communicating from the appengine app to the python app via get requests that are handled by the python script.

The problem is, that obviously the machine running the python script will be behind a firewall, I've never needed to do this before and am not sure on how to implement this best.

The only idea I have so far is for the python script to send post requests to the appengine with some data and then as a response, send back some other data. The only problem with this is that the web interface should update the client quite fast.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more detail on how your current front-end is built, how the updating happens, and what type of data (file, key-value pairs, etc) you are sending. Also, have you considered running everything on GAE or is there a reason to run python script locally?

Comment: It's quite a simple system, just sending strings to the python script in order to update it and also sending strings from the python script to the appengine instance to keep the web interface up to date with the current status of the script.

Comment: The GAE is a web interface for the service that the python script is controlling locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at ProtoRPC Python API: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/overview

Though it is still marked as experimental, it seems to be a decent framework for what you are trying to do - send messages back and forth between the apps.

Since you said your local app runs behind a firewall, I'm assuming you cannot open up an endpoint and protect it with some form of authentication.

Once you have messages flowing, you can either use Channel API to keep the front-end updated: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview

Or if you want to go more basic, just implement long/short polling through AJAX.

Sorry with the limited amount of info you have provided, that's all I can think of right now. Please feel free to post more details and I'll try to help further.